# recursive binary search condition

Tags: recursion, binary-search

I have a question about the condition of "entering" the "if condition" in the below recursive binary search:
http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/algorithms/searching/rbinarysearch.html

```cpp
int rBinarySearch(int sortedArray[], int first, int last, int key) {
   // function:
   //   Searches sortedArray[first]..sortedArray[last] for key.  
   // returns: index of the matching element if it finds key, 
   //         otherwise  -(index where it could be inserted)-1.
   // parameters:
   //   sortedArray in  array of sorted (ascending) values.
   //   first, last in  lower and upper subscript bounds
   //   key         in  value to search for.
   // returns:
   //   index of key, or -insertion_position -1 
   //                 if key is not in the array.

   if (first <= last) {
       int mid = (first + last) / 2;  // compute mid point.
       if (key == sortedArray[mid]) 
           return mid;   // found it.
       else if (key < sortedArray[mid]) 
           // Call ourself for the lower part of the array
           return rBinarySearch(sortedArray, first, mid-1, key);
       else
           // Call ourself for the upper part of the array
           return rBinarySearch(sortedArray, mid+1, last, key);
   }
   return -(first + 1);    // failed to find key
}
```

Specifically, I have a question regarding the part `if (first <= last)`.

I was trying to hand trace the step of the above recursion function. For example, I write down an array of say `[2, 5, 7, 11, 21, 26, 27, 36, 37, 42]` and let the `key` be `1`, i.e. `key = 1`.

Then I have in the first recursion, I think my `first = 0`, and `last = 9`. 
So `mid = (0 + 9)/2 = 4.5` (but mid will be `4` since `mid` is assigned to be int).

So `mid[4] > 1`, so then I have the next recursion being `(arr[], 0, 4-1=3, 1)`,..... and so on.....

However it seems that the case of `last < first` doesn't seem to appear. I am just wondering is it actually possible for the case of `last < first` to happen? (i.e.. is the condition `if (first <=last)` necessary?)

If it is necessary, could someone illustrate with a very simple example that I can hand trace with to understand that this condition is necessary?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

That condition is the stopping criterion for the case if the element that you are looking for is not an element of the array that you are searching.

In your example, if you further exercise it, the recursive calls will be

```cpp
//                   first, last
rBinarySearch(arr[],     0,    3, 1); // -> mid = 1 -> else if
rBinarySearch(arr[],     0,    0, 1); // -> mid = 0 -> else if
rBinarySearch(arr[],     0,   -1, 1); // there you go: last < first (i.e. -1 < 0)
```